# Why can't Lua table indexes be nil?

Tags: lua, lua-table, indices

Pardon if this question was already asked, but from my research, I only found questions of users having an issue with a table index being nil. My question is why can't a table index be nil/nan. I can understand why nan can't be an index, because it fails identity comparisons, but why not nil.

Comment: "An associative array is an array that can be indexed not only with numbers, but also with strings or any other value of the language, except nil." - [Programming In Lua: 2.5 – Tables](https://www.lua.org/pil/2.5.html). Why do you want `nil` as an key? there is likely a better option for the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: I don't need this behaviour, I just wanted to know as there is no documentation as to why. @Nifim

Comment: a table is an associative array also known as a hash table. the keys are transformed in to hash values, if you attempt to perform that operation on a `nil` it will cause some errors. you can find information on the hash functions here: [ltable.c](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/ltable.c.html)

Comment: IMO, `nil` as table key was prohibited to make `next()` and generators a bit simpler.